# Jquery Add Select Options

Tags: jquery

```
function build_gl_codes_select(data, level) {
if(level == 0) {
    var gl_codes_select = $("#glcb_level_one");
    $("#glcb_level_two").find('option').remove().end();
    $("#glcb_level_three").find('option').remove().end();
    $("#glcb_level_four").find('option').remove().end();
    $("#glcb_level_five").find('option').remove().end();
} else if(level == 1) {
    var gl_codes_select = $("#glcb_level_two");
    $("#glcb_level_three").find('option').remove().end();
    $("#glcb_level_four").find('option').remove().end();
    $("#glcb_level_five").find('option').remove().end();
} else if(level == 2) {
    var gl_codes_select = $("#glcb_level_three");
    $("#glcb_level_four").find('option').remove().end();
    $("#glcb_level_five").find('option').remove().end();
} else if(level == 3) {
    var gl_codes_select = $("#glcb_level_four");
    $("#glcb_level_five").find('option').remove().end();
} else if(level == 4) {
    var gl_codes_select = $("#glcb_level_five");
}

gl_codes_select.find('option').remove().end();

if(data.length > 0) {
    var option = '<option>Select Code</option>';
    gl_codes_select.append(option);
    for(i in data) {
        var option = '<option value="'+ data[i]['id']+'">'+data[i]['code']+ " " + data[i]['description']+'</option>';
        gl_codes_select.append(option);
    }
    show_code();
} else {
    var option = '<option>0 </option>';
    gl_codes_select.append(option);
    if(level == 0) {
        $("#glcb_level_two").append(option);
        $("#glcb_level_three").append(option);
        $("#glcb_level_four").append(option);
        $("#glcb_level_five").append(option);
    } else if(level == 1) {
        $("#glcb_level_three").append(option);
        $("#glcb_level_four").append(option);
        $("#glcb_level_five").append(option);
    } else if(level == 2) {
        $("#glcb_level_four").append(option);
        $("#glcb_level_five").append(option);
    } else if(level == 3) {
        $("#glcb_level_five").append(option);
    }

    show_code();
}
```

}

I run this code, level ==0, 
data contains

```
Object
code:"4"
description:"Revenue & COGS" id :"1"
```

Plus 4 more "options".  But nothing is every added to the select. I've console logged inside the if statements, we are reaching the one I expect.  The options are looped through, they just never get added to the select.  I've double checked, the select is not being cleared anywhere I can find in any of the other code.  What is really frustrating, is this exact code works on another page. I've checked the obvious things.

There are no javascript errors that I can see.

I've tried building all the options, and then appending them to the select.

I've tried using jquery .each to loop through.

I've logged the options string, and it looks like this

```
<option value="29">5 Warehouse</option>
```

Even weirder:  When I intentionally add an error condition, the select gets populated.

Comment: Looks like it works to me: https://jsfiddle.net/eudzdnxa/  (all I changed was removing the show_code() call.)

Comment: I've tried removing the show_code() call in my code, and that didn't do it for me.

Comment: I didn't mean that `show_code()` was necessarily causing the problem; I was saying that the code you've posted here appears to work correctly (assuming that the results shown in my jsfiddle are what you expect them to be).  Whatever issue you're having is elsewhere in your codebase.